# winsock2 calls are slow than Linux by 10

Tags: performance, ubuntu, networking, windows-7, winsock2

My client/server program runs much slower on Win7 than on Ubuntu 16.04.
While investigating it I narrowed down to as simple code as a loop of two winsock2 calls - socket() & closesocket():

```
int counter = 0;
while (1)
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("socket() failed!\n");
        break;
    }
    closesocket(sock);  // close(sock); on Linux

    counter++;
    if (counter % 100000 == 0)
    {
        ...  // statistic calculation using GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() / clock_gettime() on Linux
    }
}
```

Every 100.000 iterations I print the "number of iterations/seconds" statistic.
On Win7 I get **~64.000** iterations/sec, on Ubuntu **~760.000** iterations/sec.

Win7 Professional, 64 bits, i7-860 @ 2.8 GHz.
Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bits, i7-2800 @ 3.4 GHz.

Win32 and x64 builds give pretty same numbers, debug builds and release (optimized for speed)  builds have x10 difference between Win7 and Linux.

iPerf (iPerf -N -4 -c 127.0.0.1 / iPerf -s) shows **3.6** GBit/sec on Win7 and **76** GBit/sec on Ubuntu!

What can be a reason for such poor winsock2 performance?
I will be glad to test any suggestion in real time UTC +2:00 :)

Comment: Why do you care? Is opening and closing sockets really such a bottleneck for you?

Comment: Looks like it is. My application runs 10 times slower on Windows than on Linux, and socket / system calls are 10 times slower. That doesn't make sense, so I would be happy to get skilled opinion before I commit code.